# How to click on link using Selenium in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver

HTML code:

```
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="row align-items-center mb-4">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Data and Tools</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

      <a href="/reports">
        <div class="row my-4 align-items-center clickable">
          <div class="col my-3">
            <span class="semi-bold">Reports</span>
            <div class="stamp-md">
              Create, run and schedule reports.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-1 text-right">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right gray-light small"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <hr class="inner-divider">
```

Ruby code:

```
wait.until { @browser_def.find_element(css: ".card-body > a")}.attribute("href").text("Reports").click()
```

How can I click link which stands for 'Reports'?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. [Images of code are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). You have access to the plaintext; please copy and paste the code into your question.

Comment: thanks:-)question was corrected

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct answer for it:

```
wait.until { @browser_def.find_elements(css: 'a[href$="/reports"] div.clickable').first}.click()
```